# JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, metadata

Im a newbie with Json stuff. I have a project and am using Newtonsoft. I have this object

`

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Data
    {

        [JsonProperty]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty]
        public string Source { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public object SourceData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public bool IsClickable { get; set; } = true;

        [JsonConstructor]
        public Data(string Source = "", string SourceData = "", bool IsActive = false, bool IsClickable = true)
        {
            this.IsActive = IsActive;
            this.Source = Source;
            this.SourceData = SourceData;
            this.IsClickable = IsClickable;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
            Data data = new Data() { IsActive = true, Source = "test", SourceData = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, IsClickable = false };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, JsonSettings);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Data dataDes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, JsonSettings);
            Console.WriteLine(dataDes);
        }
    }
}
```

`

So when it gets serialized I get this :

`

```
{
  "IsActive": true,
  "Source": "test",
  "SourceData": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "$values": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  "IsClickable": false
}
```

`

But when it gets deserialized I get this error :
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'SourceData', line 4, position 17.'

Have i forgotten to set something somewhere to make the Metadata work when deserialized?

Comment: Your posted JSON is not valid JSON. JSON must start and end with either `[`/`]` or `{`/`}`.

Comment: Please add a [mre] of how you serialize and deserialize your data.

Comment: Yes, this json object, is part of another json object, the json is valid, i checked online

Comment: @LoganeRamez for future reference when posting snips, please make sure it is still in a valid format so people are not immediately thinking that you have an invalid format. Oh, I should say I still recommend posting the whole thing. When it comes to parsing you may be omitting the actual issues that could be causing it.

Comment: I have edited the whole post to make it clearer.  The issue is a bit different but looks like the same issue deep down.

Comment: Keep in mind that during deserialization, the Data constructor is being used. Now, explain what is it that you serialize SourceData from and as what json data structure is the SourceData being serialized, and then during deserialization what needs the SourceData value to be for it being able to be passed it into the Data constructor...

Comment: Final edit, Managed to pinpoint a bit more where it is comming from. I added the same JsonSerializerSettings that im using in my actual program and it seems to be adding those metadata. I just dont understand why it cant read them back

Comment: Try these lines in the Main method of a test application `string myString = new List<int>();` or `string myOtherString = new int[5];`. Will building and running this succeed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your question, the issue is how you are using your object property on SourceData. When Json is serializing it is smart enough to detect that the object datatype is actually an array and handles it according.

When the object is being deserialized, it is reading your constructor with the datatype "string" and attempting to deserialize it as a string, which is why it errors out when it finds a start of an array [ and not a string ".

This modified constructor should work (Adapted with MySkullCavelsADarkPlace comment)

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Data(string Source = "", JToken SourceData = null, bool IsActive = false, bool IsClickable = true)
     {
        

        this.IsActive = IsActive;
        this.Source = Source;
        
        this.SourceData = SourceData;
        // JToken.Type will hold the type that the deseralizer for Newtonsoft.Json determine that the type is
        var sourceType = SourceData.Type;

        this.IsClickable = IsClickable;
    }
```

Comment: "_This modified constructor should work_" Maybe, maybe not. Whether it works or not as desired depends on what one would except the type for the SourceData value to be. Note that for deserializing to the object type, Newtonsoft.Json will just provide the JToken representation of the respective json data. For the json data from the question, SourceData would receive a JArray instance.

Comment: Ooo, I learned something new today. Adapted the answer for it.

Comment: Yes the error was the string specification instead of object, I've done several modifications and forget to change that. I'm sorry about the dumb question and the fact that i edited 10 thousands times, I don't really have the habit of posting questions. Now everything works as intended. Is it better to delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize a json you posted you need to create one more class, after this evertything is working properly

```
Data data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, 
   new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }
);

public class Data
{
    public DropdownData DropdownData {get;set;}
}
```

UPDATE

Since you changed your question, it is working too

```
var data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DropdownData>(json, 
new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All } );
```